# how to convert Flatbuffer data file to json?

Tags: flatbuffers

I used flatbuffer to encode data into a file named 'person.txt', how can I convert it into a json file ?

I trying 'flatc --json person.txt person.json' but it failed.

I have 'person.fbs, person.txt', How to do it ?

Comment: Unrelated tip: A FlatBuffer is a binary file. Calling it .txt is about the least correct extension you could choose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to provide path of schema too in the command you are executing.

```
flatc.exe --raw-binary -t <path to fbs schema file> -- <path to flatbuffer binary file>
```